# Images.xcassets bug upon Archive or Build for running

Tags: ios, xcode, image, compilation

Suddenly faced this two asset compiler errors upon Archive or Build for running:

/Users/borislariushin/Documents/Pilgrimapp/ios/ios/Images.xcassets: Failed to write PNG data for the launch image set from "LaunchImage.launchimage/1024_768-1.png" to "/Users/borislariushin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PilgrimApp-bfjwfpphvtnwqiaqkihxoimthbkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PilgrimApp.app/LaunchImage-Landscape~ipad.png".

/Users/borislariushin/Documents/Pilgrimapp/ios/ios/Images.xcassets: Failed to write PNG data for the launch image set from "LaunchImage.launchimage/2048_1536-1.png" to "/Users/borislariushin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PilgrimApp-bfjwfpphvtnwqiaqkihxoimthbkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PilgrimApp.app/LaunchImage-Landscape@2x~ipad.png".

Any ideas how can I get rid of them and successfully compile project.

Comment: Have you tried to clean project, delete derived data and rebuild again? This worked for me.

Comment: Yes, did it. And further more rm -rf /Users/borislariushin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PilgrimApp-bfjwfpphvtnwqiaqkihxoimthbkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PilgrimApp.app/ folder. Tried aslo repairing permission on my mac.

Comment: removed and inserted back xcassets in project. This happened first time I've tried to Archive project. Before it was compiling as good as it gets.

Comment: Odd behavior indeed. Try to remove images from Assets and readd them already named correctly (I mean LaunchImage-Landscape@2x~ipad.png). Plus worth to try in new Xcode beta, if you're not using it already.

Comment: That what I am going to do: 1.get rid of xcasset and readd images manually named correctly. 2. I am using XCode 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: Damn I love xcassets they look so nice. But second time it gets me down.

Comment: What I did to get this curse off. I've opened Terminal, cd to given /Users/borislariushin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PilgrimApp-bfjwfpphvtn‌​wqiaqkihxoimthbkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PilgrimApp.app/ open command it and copied AppIcon* and LaunchImage* to my project folder and adding it to project target. Phooof! It compiled and done me an Archive.

Comment: I bought myself WatchDog App tool to clean the XCode Derived Data, but nevertheless either XCode upgraded and fixed itself more or less, or my WatchDog saves my time on automated cleanups.

Comment: @BorisLariushin I'm having the same horrible bug.  I don't understand what u mean when you say you copied all the AppIcons and LaunchImages and added them to your project target.

Comment: What is a project target?

Comment: Yes, I am also getting this error while running my App from Xcode 8 into iPhone with iOS8.0.

Answer (score 10):

you can just remove that debug folder, then it fixed.

```
rm -r /Users/borislariushin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PilgrimApp-bfjwfpphvtnwqiaqkihxoimthbkp
```

Comment: this just happend to me too. I had to remove all the debug folders for the app and then it worked

Comment: Happened to me  with XCode 8 and removing all the debug folders worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Cocoapods** Remove file **.xcworkspace** then again run **Terminal** type

```
pod install
```

works 100%

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the build folder worked for me

Product->Clean Build Folder